# Optimize a transformation from a 2-dim numpy array with day of the year values (doy) into an array with date values

Tags: python, arrays, datetime

Does anyone know how to optimize a transformation from a 2-dim numpy array with day of the year values (doy) into 
an array with date values?
The function below works but unfortunately in an very inelegant way. I would be very happy if anyone has a good idea
how to avoid the loop over the 2-dim array which should make the calculation faster for large datesets.

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

#test 2-dim array with doy values
doy = np.array([[272, 272],
                [274, 274]])

#define start and end date
startdat = datetime.datetime.strptime('2012 10 01 0000', '%Y %m %d %H%M')
year_start = int(startdat.strftime('%Y'))
enddat = datetime.datetime.strptime('2013 09 30 0000', '%Y %m %d %H%M')
year_end = int(enddat.strftime('%Y'))

#initialise an tmp array
res_date = np.zeros([2,2]) 

#transform doy into date    
for x in range(2):
    for y in range(2):
        if doy[x,y] >= 274 and doy[x,y] <= 365:
            datum = date.fromordinal(date(year_start, 1, 1).toordinal() + doy[x,y])
            datum = datum.strftime('%Y%m%d')    
            res_date[x,y]= datum
        else:
            datum = date.fromordinal(date(year_end, 1, 1).toordinal() + doy[x,y])
            datum = datum.strftime('%Y%m%d')    
            res_date[x,y]= datum
#that's my result
#res_date = array([[ 20130930.,  20130930.],
                  #[ 20121001.,  20121001.]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this kind of thing

```
offset = (datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 30) - datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 31)).days
yearlen = (datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1) - datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1)).days
doy[doy >= offset] -= yearlen
dates = np.datetime64('2013-01-01') + doy
```

but to extract YMD from the datetime64 values is a bit tricky. The consensus is to use pandas. Why do you need the array to be in that format?

EDIT, I've added the calculation yearlen but I haven't thought through all the permutations, you probably need to check that with a calendar!

Further EDIT. From your next phrasing of the question your doy looks to be simply days from 2011,9,30 (or from 2011,10,1 minus 1). i.e.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

#counting the doys from the 1. of October to the 30 of September
doy = np.array([[0, 4],
                [7, 93]])

#read start and enddat
startdat = datetime.datetime(2011,10,1)
dates = np.datetime64(startdat).astype('datetime64[D]') + doy - 1

# NB I don't think the datetime64 format takes too much space 'inside' numpy
# it just looks bulky. From the name I would assume it uses a 64 bit integer
# which is only 8 bytes for each value in memory (standard integers are 32 bits
#
#... but if you want to convert to floats this is a rather ugly way of doing it
# NB it's specifically 2D array and rather undoes the whole point of using numpy!
dates = np.array([[d.year * 10000 + d.month * 100 + d.day for d in c]
                                 for c in dates.tolist()], dtype=np.float)
print('raw version\n', dates)
dates[doy == 0] = np.nan
print('nan version\n', dates)

#raw version
# [[ 20110930.  20111004.]
# [ 20111007.  20120101.]]
#nan version
# [[       nan  20111004.]
# [ 20111007.  20120101.]]
```

Comment: Hi, thx a lot, your code works fine! What do you mean with: 'Need the array in that format'. My res_date array (the result array with the date values) don't need to be in a dtype float format. I also don't understand what do you mean with 'have to use more date arithmatic to fix leap years!' Right now I have no good idea how to handle the leap years in an efficient way. And yes, working with datetime format is quiet tricky! :)

Comment: @angi, if you're happy to end up with an array of datetime values rather than convert to 20131001 format that's ideal. The point about the leap years is that if the val in doy is greater than your year cut off (274, say) then you want that value to be taken as the doy of the previous year, but if the previous year was a leap year (as in this case) then doy 274 falls on a different date i.e. doy 274 in 2012 was 1st Oct but in 2013 was 2nd. You need to work a value out rather than just use 365. I will do an edit.

Comment: @angi, was this the correct answer, or do you need any other help?

Comment: dear paddyg, sorry for awnsering so late!! I still need help with the datetime transformation. I posted my code in the awnser below. It would be great if you have an idea how to handle this problem.

Comment: just to confirm what you are trying to do: doy is a numerical, unbroken sequential number to be interpreted as days after 2011-09-30. i.e. doy=1 is 2011-10-1 and doy 92 is 2011-12-31 and doy 93 is 2012-1-1 If this is the case then you can just add the array to the datetime(2011,9,30)

Comment: dear paddyg, your code is really efficient and helped me to avoid all these offset calculations. Thank you very much! I didn't know that it is so easy to just calculate the dates from the startdat. Thk a lot!

Comment: Now I have one more question. How would you handle 0 values in a datetime64[D] array? Zero values stand for missing values (NAs) meaning that this elements don't fullfill the conditions to calculate a doy value. And how is it possible to convert an np.datetime64[D] array into a float to save memory capacity? Greetings, angi @ you are really a datetime specialist! @ you find my code in awnser 3. Unfortunately I can just do this with an array in a string format!

Comment: @angi, I thought of a way to convert to floats. Not ideal as I say in the comment. PS if you feel this has answered your question, please remember to mark it as correct (especially so it's not confused with your variation/further questions) PPS I'm not a datetime expert - never used it before within numpy. But I have been programming for a long time!!

Comment: Hi peddyg, thx you a lot for showing me a little bit around in the datetime world. Yeah, you are right it make less sense and it is ugly to convert a dtype datetime array back into a dtype float array. But in my case it is ok in order to keep all my data consistent. But why are you multiplying the d.year with 10000 and d.month with 100? Is this the ugly way to get a float format out of a datetime format? Greets,

Comment: as far as I can see that is the format you are using: year * 10000 + month * 100 + day. The only alternative would be a REALLY horrible process of producing a formatted string then converting that back into a number. (Don't forget to mark the answer correct once you're happy, this is what stackoverflow relies on)

Comment: @angi are you still considering these answers?

Comment: Hi paddyg, yes, so multiply an datetime array with date format (year * 10000 + month * 100 + day) is alternativly the best way to get out a number of an datetime array. Yet, I marked my favourit awnser. Thank you for reminding me about this process. I didn't know that stackoverflow exepect this - but it make sense. Thank you again for helping me with all the datetime transformations. Best wishes,

Answer (score 0):

sry for awnsering so late. I hoped I could find a way to go around all this datetime
transfromation. But unfortunately there is no way to go around and I'm still confused with all this
transfromations, dayshifts and leap years.
My Problem is still the same: How to get a corect date from my doy-time-values, which starts counting a
year from the 1. October until the 30. of September. So in order to get
a correct date out of this doy-time-values I tried to correct the offset first. The last time I gave you the
corrected offset values and you gave ma an elegant code to convert the correced doys into
a date. Secondly I tried to convert the corrected doys into a date.
Below you find the the whole code including your part. The code works well for non
leap years. But I still dont know how to handle the leap years and to get a correct date even
for leap years. Mabey you have an idea how to handel the leap years and mabey there is
better way for the offset correction. Yet my dates within a leap year including an
offset of 2 days. Oh this datetime transformations are really a bit confusing.
Would be great if you have an idea how to handle this problem. Thank you so far!

## convert doy into date

```
#import modules
import numpy as np
import datetime
import copy

#test_data
#counting the doys from the 1. of October to the 30 of September
doy = np.array([[152, 4],
                [7, 93]])

#read start and enddat
startdat = datetime.datetime.strptime('2011 10 01 0000', '%Y %m %d %H%M')
enddat = datetime.datetime.strptime('2012 09 30 0000', '%Y %m %d %H%M')
year_startdat = int(startdat.strftime('%Y'))
year_enddat = int(enddat.strftime('%Y'))
yeardays = (enddat - startdat) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

#correct the doy offset in order to transfrom doy into a date
doy_corr = copy.copy(start_max)
if yeardays == datetime.timedelta(366):
    print 'is leap year!'
    doy_corr[(doy >=1.) & (doy <= 92)] += 274
    doy_corr[(doy >=93.) & (doy <= 366)] -= 93
#correct the doy offset if there is no leap year
else:
    print 'no leap year!'    
    doy_corr[(doy >=1.) & (doy <= 92)] += 273
    doy_corr[(doy >=93.) & (doy <= 365)] -= 93

#transform doy corrected into date. The offset is necessary to get the correct year
offset = (datetime.datetime(year_enddat, 9, 30) - datetime.datetime(year_startdat, 12, 31)).days
yearlen = (datetime.datetime(year_enddat, 1, 1) - datetime.datetime(year_startdat, 1, 1)).days
doy_corr[doy_corr >= offset] -= yearlen
dates = np.datetime64(str(year_enddat)+('-01-01')) + doy_corr

#my result should be 
#array([['2012-02-29', '2011-10-04'],
#      ['2011-10-07', '2012-01-01']], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Answer (score 0):

How to replace Zeros (Zeros stand for missing values) in an np.datetime array with NA-values and how to convert a np.datetime64 array into a float or an int array?

```
#import modules
import numpy as np
import datetime

#counting the doys from the 1. of October to the 30 of September
#Zero stands for NA
doy = np.array([[0, 4],
                [7, 93]])

#define to startdat to receive dates from 1. of October 
startdat = datetime.datetime(2011,10,1)
dates = np.datetime64(startdat).astype('datetime64[D]') + doy - 1
print(dates)
#convert the datetime array into a string
dates_str = np.datetime_as_string(dates)
#replace the false date-values with NA
ind = np.where(dates_str == '2011-09-30')
dates_str[ind] = 'NA'

#My favored result:
#array([[nan, 20111004.],
#       [20111007., '20120101.]], 
#      dtype='float')
```